# How Can I Put type() with if statement in python?

Tags: python, math, if-statement, type-conversion, typeerror

I have `TypeError: a float is required` when I try putting type() with if statement

example:

```
from math import *
x=input("Enter a Number: ")
if type (sqrt(x)) == int:
    print (sqrt(x))
else:
    print("There is no integer square root")
```

obviously I can't use `x= float(x)`

Comment: “obviously I can’t use `x= float(x)`” – why not?

Comment: Use the `float.is_integer` method to test if a float is an int.

Comment: You can also use `isinstance`.

Comment: There's no question of types here. input returns a string, period. You need to convert that to a float (x = float(x) will work just fine) before passing it to sqrt().

Comment: I image you are getting the error `TypeError: a float is required`.  That's because `x` is a string.  You can't take a square root of a string.  Do note that even if you do `sqrt(float(x))` your if-statement will never evaluate to true because `math.sqrt` always returns a float.

Comment: You should also be aware that using floats at all is going to be a problem if you want to be able to deal with arbitrarily large integer input.  For example, `sqrt(10**33).is_integer()` gives `True`, but `10**33` is not a square number. But integer inputs smaller than `4503599627370497` should be okay.

Answer (score 3):

there are 2 problems here :

1st

```
x=input("Enter a Number: ")
```

will be a string, not a number, using `int(x)` should fix this

2nd

```
if type (sqrt(x)) == int:
```

`sqrt()` always return a float, you can use `float.is_integer()`, like this : `sqrt(x)).is_integer()` to check if the square root is a integer.

final code :

```
    from math import *
    x=int(input("Enter a Number: "))
    if sqrt(x).is_integer():
        print (sqrt(x))
    else:
        print("There is no integer square root")
```

Comment: I suggest `sqrt(x).is_integer()` rather than `float.is_integer(sqrt(x))`.  There's no need for the unbound method here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your input string to float *before* passing it to sqrt(). As far as Python is concerned, `sqrt("5.4")` makes no more sense than `sqrt("Bob")`. And `x=float(x)` is a fine way to do that conversion.

There's no question of types here: `input()` will *always* be string, and `sqrt()` will *always* be float (never int).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that instead of an int, you just want a whole number. To check if something is a whole number, do a modulus division by 1.

```
from math import *
x = float(input("Enter a Number: "))
if sqrt(x) % 1 == 0:
    print(sqrt(x))
else:
    print("There is no integer square root")
```